# How to print each row value one by one in php codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I tried to get the all the rows of a database and it should loop itself for expected output. The image of the output is [enter image description here][1]

And the code is as follows:
In model:

```
function get_menugroup() 
 {
    $data=array();
    $sql = $this->db->query("SELECT MenuName FROM MenuGroup;");
    $menu_res = $sql->result();   
        if($sql -> num_rows() > 0 ) 
        {   
                return $menu_res;
        }
        else{
            echo "Nothing to process";
        }

}`
```

In controller

```
public function menugroupname()
{

        $menugroups=$this->UserRight_model->get_menugroup(); 
        if ($menugroups){       
        $data['menu'] = $menugroups;

        //$data['count'] = count($data['menu']);
        $this->load->view('UserRight_view',$data);      
        }   
}
```

In view:

```
<ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
                    <li>
                    <?php 
                    if(is_array($menu)){
                     foreach($menu as $menus){
                     $menulist = $menus ->MenuName; 
                     //$menulist = $menus['MenuName'];
                     $fun = explode(",",$menus ->MenuName); 
                                            }
                     $no_menu = count($menu);
                      //echo $no_menu;
                     for($i=0; $i<$no_menu ; $i++){ 
                     ?>
                     <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i><?php echo $menulist ?></div>
                      <div class="collapsible-body"><p>Submenu.</p></div>
                    </li>
                    <?php }} else { echo "Wrong way";} ?>


            </ul>
```

And thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
    <li>
    <?php 
    if(($menu)){
     foreach($menu[0] as $menus){
     $menulist = $menus->MenuName; 
     $fun = explode(",",$menus ->MenuName);                             }
     $no_menu = count($menu);
     for($i=0; $i<$no_menu ; $i++){ 
     ?>
     <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i><?php echo $menulist ?></div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><p>Submenu.</p></div>
    </li>
    <?php }} else { echo "Wrong way";} ?>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: In my menu I have 5 items, but all the items are taken as array[0]...May i know why? Because i want to print the first row while first iteration... and when it executes second iteration, it should print second row.... but all the rows print last row's value...

Comment: You should attach code for get_menugroup() function.

Comment: Hi i included get_menugroup() function in the beginning of the conversation

Comment: function get_menugroup() { $data=array(); $sql = $this->db->query("SELECT MenuName FROM MenuGroup;"); $menu_res = $sql->result();
if($sql -> num_rows() > 0 ) {
return $menu_res; } else{ echo "Nothing to process"; }

}`

Comment: Try my updated code. if its not working then var_dump($menu); and attach result here